# Apple Earbuds + Nexus 6p

Tags: headphones, headphone-jack, nexus-6p

I just got a Nexus 6p. Today, I plugged in apple earbuds and found that the phone doesn't recognize them (which struck me as odd because both the Nexus 6 and Nexus 4 support those headphones).

After a little bit of experimenting I found that the phone will recognize the headphones if I hold down the microphone button on the inline controls, but not otherwise (also, releasing the button causes the phone to stop recognizing them).

Can anyone else confirm this is an issue with the device? Or is it a hardware problem on my device?

Thanks so much,

### Edit

Ordered a replacement, apple earbuds work great. Problem seems to have been a hardware failure.

Comment: Are you talking about the EarPods? If yes, then they're working on my Nexus 6P perfectly, save the inline volume controls. The microphone button pauses music on a short press, and skips the current track to the next on pressing it twice in rapid succession. Long pressing it open Google Voice Search.

Comment: I am -- alright, sounds like a hardware fault on my side. Thanks @DhruvilMehta! If you want to answer the question, I can mark you right answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple EarPods are  working on my Nexus 6P perfectly, save the inline volume controls. The microphone button pauses music on a short press, and skips the current track to the next on pressing it twice in rapid succession. Long pressing it open Google Voice Search.